# Converting dates in contracts using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert date formats that look like this "the 16 day of January, 2020" to a standard date format such as "01/16/2020". Is there a way I can do this using python? If someone can guide me in the right direction I will really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried regEx to extract parts of date from text and create a date using extracted day, month, year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mydate = 'the 16 day of January, 2020'
for item in ['the ', ' day of', ","]:
     mydate= mydate.replace(item, '')
print (mydate)

from dateutil import parser
mydate = parser.parse(mydate)
print (mydate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

This should give you:

```
16 January 2020
01/16/2020
```